# can not login in production /django

Tags: django, authentication, web-applications, superuser

I successfully deployed my django webapp but now I am unable to login as superuser even if I put correct credentials

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEFfe.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "deployed" means a new environment, you have to migrate everything and create a new superuser.

BTW you can dump your db with

```
manage.py dumpdata > dump.json
```

and load to the new environment with:

```
manage.py loaddata "path/to/file/dump.json"
```

For more information: [dumpdata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata) and [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#loaddata)